# How to store secrets like API keys and client IDs for Xamarin?

Tags: security, xamarin, secret-key

I'm developing a cross-platform application with Xamarin which includes 3rd party SSO like Facebook and Google+. This involves storing client ids, API secrets and other sensitive information to be able to connect to the mentioned SSO providers.
I solved this several times with Gradle when I was developing Android, but I thought I'd give Xamarin a shot, but I didn't find any solution or best practice for this kind of sensitive data storing. And the official Xamarin forum is also very quite about it :'(

Comment: Did you see this thread thread in the Xamarin forum? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42869/storing-sensitive-user-security-data

Comment: There's a few ways to go about it. A couple off the top of my head would be to follow a similar approach that @dennisschroeer posted in which you can Encrypt/Decrypt your Files or values inside the files and save those safely. The other way would be to setup your build process to depend on external files that include these values and are only added at Build time and thus needed to successfully build. These are items that would not be committed to source control so there's no chance of these ever leaking to the general public if your provider got hacked in any way.

Comment: @JonDouglas That's exactly what I was thinking about! Some kind of (key, value) store which can be distributed separately and can be left out from source control. But the build would now about it and include those during the process, create a file of constants or substitute fake values with real ones. But I'm new to Xamarin Studio and I don't if there is a built in functionality or something for this. I'm gonna check the other dennis's link.

Comment: @dennisschroeer Answer is more about storing sensitive data collected from the user or 3rd party and storing securely on the device. My question is more about leaving out "constant" values from the source code.